# Cant see variables from parent function in a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write a directive which will handle "Enter" clicks, here's my code:

```
directive('onEnter', function() {
    return {
        link:   function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.keyup(function(e) {
                        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                            debugger;
                        }
                    });
                }
    }
});
```

The problem is that inside the callback (where the debugger is), I can't access scope, element and attrs.
Any help?

Comment: so send your `scope` as an argument to your debugger

Comment: it should work as it is a closure variable

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uznLH/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Arun P Johny, I found the problem.
Apparently if you do not use a variable in a callback, some JS optimization (tested on chrome and firefox, this issue doesn't happen in firefox) doesn't pass the variable to the callback.
Since, in my example, I put a debugger and didn't use any of the variables (scope, element, attrs) JS just didn't pass them on.
Thanks.